# How to evenly split a graph into equal-sized subgraphs using pytorch/pytorch-geometric?

Tags: pytorch, graph-theory, pytorch-geometric

Suppose I have an undirected graph ***G*** of `n` nodes and `e` edges which are represented as edge list ***E*** of shape `[2, e]`.
How can I split it into `k` subgraphs each containing `m` nodes (`k*m>=n`) as evenly as possible? One vertex can be included in multiple subgraphs.